# Postgres User Error - Dependencies

Tags: python, git, postgresql

I am trying to run a project and install some dependencies for it. These are

- Git
- Postgres 8.2 or later
- Python 2.5 or later
- Java runtime
- Python `virtual-env` and some other dev packages as well (`python-dev`, `libpq-dev` and `libxslt-dev`).

Therefore I am doing

`sudo ./scripts/install_dependencies.sh`

Everything goes according to plan but then at end of it I get this error in the terminal:

`creating postgres user nick
createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "nick" already exists`

I had limited experience with `Postgres` but I am not sure what is the problem.

Any ideas? Should I try to drop the user or?

When I do for example

`psql -l`

I get this:

```
 List of databases
     Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
---------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 blablabalblal | nick     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 smthing2      | nick     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)
```

I am seeing two databases with the same name as author but I am not sure what the next step should be.

Also when I do `psql --help` I get this info along with other things:

`database user name (default: "nick")`

I installed PostgreSQL 9.3.

Maybe is an error of the script I am trying to run and `Postgres` is properly configured?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't drop the user, the user you want to create is already exist. Comment out the `create user` on the script will do.

Comment: Hm ok thanks for the suggestion I will try it and report back asap.